# Is there a way to change column Default value to blank for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, default-value

I have a situation where the value of the field is removed the column default value doesn't get changed to blank. I have tried directly removing the default value from the column but I get the error "Please enter a valid default value. It must not be blank". Any idea on how to remove the value once it is set.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a bit more detail a screenshot of the column definition would help. What type of column is it? Is the column itself required? Then it cannot be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's how you're trying to do it?  When you're in the list, try going to the gear, list settings, click on the column name to edit, delete the default value, and hit OK.  That worked without issue for me, anyhow.  #fingerscrossed!

Comment: I am going gear--> library settings --> Column default value settings then clicking on the column's name and removing the value from Default Value text-box. and pressing ok but it gives me error saying default value can't be blank, I am unable unclick the "use this default value" radio button

Answer (score 0):

**Please perform the following troubleshooting：**

1.Please delete the Default value. Click on the column name >> **Column settings** >> **Edit**.

[image]

2.Please make sure disable "**Require that this column contains information**" option.

[image]

3.Please refresh page and clear browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It's the "Do not specify a default value for this location" button that is missing.

If you open the URL in Edge or Internet Explorer it will appear. Seems to be a bug affecting Chrome users.